# Why a parameter is passed to FragmentStateAdapter when subclassing it?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewpager

I'm following [Android's tutorial on ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide-2.html#viewpager) and their source code show the following adapter subclass:

```
private inner class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(fa: FragmentActivity) : FragmentStateAdapter(fa) {
        override fun getItemCount(): Int = NUM_PAGES

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment = ScreenSlidePageFragment()
    }
```

My question is why does the class I extend (`FragmentStateAdapter`) require a parameter? `fa` is already passed to my `ScreenSlidePagerAdapter` so why isn't it just:

```
private inner class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(fa: FragmentActivity) : FragmentStateAdapter() {
```

?

Comment: Your link does not go to an actual Web page.

Comment: the subclass knows about its  superclass but the superclass does not know about its child 
and because FragmentStateAdapter has no empty constructor its mandatory to pass  the parameter to it